# Detect image who a max-width applied

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to add a class to all image that are concerned by max-width css property.

In a div for example, I have two images : 
Number 1 : width 200 & height 200
Number 2 : width 50 & height 50

I have a property max-width on my div : max-width:50px

Can I detect through jquery or else, that my image is resized by the css property ?

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding of your problem here is how you can solve it.

```
var $imageContainer = $("div");
var maxWidth = $imageContainer.css('max-width');
$imageContainer.find('img').filter(function(){
      return $(this).height() > maxWidth;
})
.addClass('maxWidth');//Define this class with appropriate styles
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have any sort of internal "css value" selector.  You can build one, but you may just want to do something like

```
$("img").each(function() {
   if ($(this).css('max-width') == '50px') {
      $(this).addClass('detected');
   }
});
```